# Modifying contents of android dialog not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my android app, I create a dialog box, and then dynamically add rows to it. This is what I got

The problem is, that when the dialog shows up, there is no contents. When I debug it, it does go through all the code and adds it to the table....

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_history, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.history)).setCancelable(true);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)dialoglayout;

        for (HistoryItem item : historyList) {
            if (item.getFishId() == fish_id) {
                User user = item.getUser();

                TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                row.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);

                ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
                layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageview.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);

                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
                layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView nameview = new TextView(context);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                nameview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
                nameview.setText(user.getName());

                TextView actionview = new TextView(context);
                textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                actionview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
                actionview.setText(item.getType());

                TextView commentview = new TextView(context);
                textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                commentview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
                commentview.setText(item.getComment());

                TextView dateview = new TextView(context);
                textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                dateview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
                dateview.setText(MyDate.dateToString(item.getDate()));

                layout.addView(nameview);
                layout.addView(actionview);
                layout.addView(commentview);
                layout.addView(dateview);

                row.addView(imageview);
                row.addView(layout);
                table.addView(row);
            }
        }

        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.show();
```

And the xml file it loads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you are adding views to your `table` but in the end you are adding the `dialogLayout` to the `builder`. Try this:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
....

builder.setView(table);
builder.show();
```

If it doesn't work try upload a image of what you are trying to achieve. I'am sure i can help

Answer (score 0):

Try with custom Dialog :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_history); // here set the custom layout
                dialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.history));
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) dialog .findViewById(dialog_layout_root);

for (HistoryItem item : historyList) {

    if (item.getFishId() == fish_id) {
            User user = item.getUser();

            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);

            ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
            layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layoutmargin = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutmargin);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            TextView nameview = new TextView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            nameview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
            nameview.setText(user.getName());

            TextView actionview = new TextView(context);
            textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            actionview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
            actionview.setText(item.getType());

            TextView commentview = new TextView(context);
            textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            commentview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
            commentview.setText(item.getComment());

            TextView dateview = new TextView(context);
            textmargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            dateview.setLayoutParams(textmargin);
            dateview.setText(MyDate.dateToString(item.getDate()));

            layout.addView(nameview);
            layout.addView(actionview);
            layout.addView(commentview);
            layout.addView(dateview);

            row.addView(imageview);
            row.addView(layout);
            table.addView(row);
        }
    } 
dialog.show ;
```